# What's the difference between prototype[name] and prototype.name?

Tags: javascript

I am reading the book Javascript the good part and there is a example

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func){
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    // this.prototype.name = func;
    return this;
};

Number.method("integer", function(){
    return Math[this<0 ? "ceiling" : "floor"](this);
});

document.writeln((10/3).integer());
```

I thought this.prototype[name] = func; and this.prototype.name = func; are the same thing but it seems they aren't.

When I ran the commented out statement in Chrome, it showed an error

"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

So what's wrong with the statement? Isn't it assigning func to name?

Thanks

Comment: Quasi-related: `ceil` not `ceiling`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil

Comment: Hi, I tested on Chrome both ceiling and ceil are working, but still thanks

Answer (score 5):

The expression

```
this.prototype.name = func;
```

assigns a value to the "name" property of the prototype object.  By contrast, this

```
this.prototype[name] = func;
```

assigns a value to a property whose name is determined by the string value of the variable "name". The difference is that with a simple `.` reference, the identifier itself is taken as the property name. With `[]`, the expression within the brackets is evaluated, and *that* is taken to be the property name.

Note that your "integer" method is explicitly taking advantage of that behavior just a few lines down!